# Laravel app developed and uploaded to bluehost server

Tags: php, laravel, bluehost

I have been given a laravel chatting application which has been developed by another developer. I have uploaded it to blue-host server but many of the functionalities are not working, like email verification, invitation through email etc. I am confused if it needs extra configuration to get to work. Because i have just uploaded it like as we upload a normal site. This is the [link](http://www.lexingtonavenuemagazine.com/) you can check .

Comment: We're not going to go register accounts just to test your system. Give us specific things that aren't working, including relevant code and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like email related stuff is not working. There are settings for .env that are probably used by application to send emails. Edit them with your info.

Defaults are:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```